# Adding without MaterialApp return black screen

Tags: flutter

I have written the following simple flutter app. I am trying to write this without MaterialApp.
Earlier the error for Directionality was coming which i am able to solve by using Directionality Widget.Even without using Theme it is showing black screen and no output. Kindly correct the error

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }

}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double maxbid = 0.0;

  void changeBid() {
    setState(() {
      maxbid += 10.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return
    Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.white,buttonColor: Colors.blue),
      child:
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, child: Text("your Current bid is $maxbid",)),
                new Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, child: FlatButton.icon(

                    onPressed: changeBid,
                    label: Text("Click to increase Bid",),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle)
                )),

              ],


            )
    );

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Widget need [Material](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Material-class.html) over it to build widget, so you can correct it by just wrapping Theme widget with Material Widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Material(  //added widget
        child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context)
```